# UISplitViewController programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I'd like to know if it is possible to have a usual ViewController with a button, and when you click the button it displays a new Controller divided into two controller with the uisplitviewcontroller?
In others forum, I've seen people explaining how to use the AppDelegate and the method applicationdidfinishlaunching, but I don't want to use that method.

So, is it possible to make what I want ?

Comment: Just put the code for displaying the UISplitViewController in the method which handles the button press.

Comment: i always fail to create properly my UISplitViewController, if someone has a simple example, i would be really happy

Comment: Posting your code would be a good start, then people can let you know what you're doing wrong

Comment: Right, please post your code first.

Answer (score 0):

The SplitViewController should be the rootViewController of your app, so you should not push it or present it modally. Instead of that, just set that simple ViewController with the button as rootVC, and when you press it, change the application`s rootVC to the splitVC. Hope this helps.